# How does a tick(FPS) function exactly works inside a loop?

Tags: python, pygame

Inside a loop like

```
FPS = 30

while True:
    TICK(FPS)
    DO OTHER STUFF
```

how exactly a **tick(FPS)** function works?

For example:

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:

    clock.tick(FPS)
    # do other stuff
```

Comment: Well, the tick function will work whichever way you implement it.

Comment: i mean like `clock.tick(FPS)`

Comment: Are you asking how a "tick" function is typically implemented by graphics/game framework writers, or what a "tick" function does?

Comment: @Michael0x2a the latter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `tick` function is typically used inside games, or other programs that involve lots of graphics changing very quickly.

If we take a game as an example, the "main loop" will typically look something like this:

```
while True:
    # Handle user input
    # Do physics calculations/etc
    # Update character positions
    # Draw things to the screen
```

The game will basically loop through some variant of these steps very rapidly, as fast as it can.

This leads to a problem: sometimes, the game can loop through too fast (unplayable) or too slow (lag), making the game inconsistent in how fast it runs on different computers/etc. For example, if you tried playing some game from 10 or so years ago on modern computers, they might run way too fast, unless you manually slowed the game down.

The `tick` function is designed to address the "too fast" problem. After each loop, the `tick` function will check how much time has gone by, and pause the game for a few milliseconds to ensure that the program draws to the screen at as consistent of an interval as possible.

In general, a 'tick' function will look sometime similar to this:

```
def tick(fps):
    interval = 60 / fps 
    current_time = time()
    delta = current_time - last_time

    if delta < interval:
        sleep(interval - delta)

    last_called = time()
```

(It's probably going to be more complicated then this, to handle weird edge cases/be more efficient, but you get the general idea)

This ensures that no matter what computer you're using, or how fast your program could run, you'll always have your game run at a consistent fps, making for a better experience.

Of course, this doesn't solve the problem of lag (games running too slow vs too fast), but that's an entirely different problem :)

Comment: He's asking about http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick

Comment: In this case the documentation you linked, says it all.